# PHP parsing json from xml file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, parsing

I'm somewhat familliar with xml and json parsing but Im having a problem with this site. I tried

```
$json_string="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/plus/timeline/timeline_radar_si_short.xml"; 
$json = file_get_contents($json_string); 
$arr=json_decode($json_string, true);
```

but it doesn't work. When i was analysing the data i found that there are some javascript variables inside json that are turned to data when javascript is run so maybe thats why it doesn't work. Not shure how to fix it thou.

What I would like to do is parse values like "9:10 CEST"... and  "si0_20140930-0710_zm_si.jpg"... into php array.

Comment: It's XML and not JSON you're trying to decode. Use `simplexml` instead.

Comment: file is xml. Then, why you are using json_decode() ?

Comment: doesnt work with xml eather

Comment: The data format on that file seems weird. It's neither XML nor JSON. No wonder the language facility isn't working. I guess you'll have to write some custom logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution works. Don't know if there's a better way to do it:

```
<?php
    $xml_string="http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/plus/timeline/timeline_radar_si_short.xml"; 
    $xml = file_get_contents($xml_string);

    // Extract relevant section out of the file
    $start_pos = strpos($xml, "timeline:") + strlen("timeline:");
    $end_pos = strpos($xml, "});");
    $json = substr($xml, $start_pos, $end_pos - $start_pos);

    // Some string replace operations to bind the keys and values within " (double quotes) 
    $json = preg_replace("/(,[a-z]+)/", '"$1', $json);
    $json = preg_replace("/([a-z]+)(:)/", '"$1"$2"', $json);
    $json = str_replace('}', '"}', $json);

    // echo $json; // This string is now in decodable json format
    $arr = json_decode($json, true);
    var_dump($arr);
    return;
?>
```

Comment: This is what i was looking for...I modified it a bit and now is perfect ! THX.

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/plus/timeline/timeline_radar_si_short.xml");
```

do not use `json_decode`.

Comment: I tried $url= file_get_contents("http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/plus/timeline/timeline_radar_si_short.xml");
$xml = simplexml_load_string($url); 
print_r($xml); but it doesnt work. It gives me SimpleXMLElement Object ( )

Answer (score 0):

This `xml` doesn't seem a valid one. 
It doesn't contain any DTD for the data rules or even the standard `<?xml..` tags, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd">
...
```

It contains also *javascript* code. SimpleXML cannot parse it either (empty array).

If you can call the javascript that it holds, do this:

```
$data = file_get_contents("http://meteo.arso.gov.si/uploads/probase/www/plus/timeline/timeline_radar_si_short.xml");
$data = str_replace(array('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><pujs><![CDATA[',']]></pujs>'),"",$data);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">'.$data."</script>";
```